# Missing Firefox add-on debugger dialog asking to accept incoming connection

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug a Firefox extension that I'm working on.
Using MacOS Mojave 10.14.1 and Firefox 63.0.3.

When I click on the Debug link below the extension that I want to debug, it is supposed that a dialog has to appear asking me to allow and incoming connection so the debug session can be started, but this dialog does not appear and the debug session fails.

The procedure is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/af/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger#Opening_the_Add-on_Debugger)

Someone knows how to fix this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else faces the same: your MacOS /etc/hosts file MUST contain a line for localhost:

127.0.0.1 localhost